# Merge and update One xml file nodes and attributes with another xml file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

hello I want to merge and update the first XMLFile1.xml file with XMLFile2.xml using XSLT. I've made transformation for another xml, but the merge nad update part is very hard for a newcomer in XSLT like me.

**XMLFile1.xml**

```
 <Sports>
          <Sport id="1" name="Soccer">
            <Tournament id="4" name="International - Womens Euro, Qualification Group 1">
              <Match id="7261871" name="Slovenia v Belarus" startDate="2015-10-19T13:00:00">
                <MatchOdds>


                  <Bet id="01">
                    <Outcome Special="0:1" name="1" odds="3.0"/>
                    <Outcome Special="0:1" name="X" odds="3.34"/>
                    <Outcome Special="0:1" name="2" odds="1.95"/>
                  </Bet>
                  <Bet id="234">
                    <Outcome Special="2.5" name="Over" odds="1.75"/>
                    <Outcome Special="2.5" name="Under" odds="2.1"/>
                  </Bet>
                  <Bet id="44444432222">
                    <Outcome Special="0:1" name="1" odds="3.0"/>
                    <Outcome Special="0:1" name="X" odds="3.85"/>
                    <Outcome Special="0:1" name="2" odds="1.95"/>
                  </Bet>
                </MatchOdds>
              </Match>
            </Tournament>
          </Sport>
        </Sports>
```

XMLFile2.xml

```
<Sports>
  <Sport id="1" name="Soccer">
    <Tournament id="4" name="International - Womens Euro, Qualification Group 1">
      <Match id="7261871" name="Slovenia v Belarus" startDate="2015-10-19T13:00:00">
        <MatchOdds>
          <Bet id="60">
            <Outcome Special="2.5" name="Over" odds="5"/>
            <Outcome Special="2.5" name="Under" odds="6"/>
          </Bet>
          <Bet id="01">
            <Outcome Special="0:1" name="1" odds="2.0"/>
            <Outcome Special="0:1" name="X" odds="3.20"/>
            <Outcome Special="0:1" name="2" odds="3.65"/>
          </Bet>

          <Bet id="398">
            <Outcome Special="0.5" name="Over" odds="2.0"/>
            <Outcome Special="0.5" name="Under" odds="1.75"/>
          </Bet>
          <Bet id="410">
            <Outcome Special="" name="Odd" odds="1.9"/>
            <Outcome Special="" name="Even" odds="1.8"/>
          </Bet>

        </MatchOdds>
      </Match>
    </Tournament>
  </Sport>
</Sports>
```

The result must be updated first file with the second. The odds attributes values are not the same like in the first file.

```
<Bet id="01">
   <Outcome Special="0:1" name="1" odds="2.0"/>
   <Outcome Special="0:1" name="X" odds="3.20"/>
   <Outcome Special="0:1" name="2" odds="3.65"/>
</Bet>
```

in XMLFile2 is not the same as XMLFile1.
Thanks in advance
GeorgiT

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.